# Spacemacs and reftex

Tags: reftex

I'm trying to configure my spacemacs install to use it with reftex. Actually, I want to change the automatic labels of equation and such so that they include the file name in the label. The end of my .spacemacs is the following

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
[snip]
 '(reftex-extra-bindings t)
 '(reftex-use-external-file-finders t)
 '(reftex-label-alist
   (quote
    (("multline" 109 "eq_%f:" "~\\ref{%s}" t ("Equation"))
     ("equation" 122 "eq_%f:" "~\\eqref{%s}" t ("Equation")))))
 '(reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
 '(ring-bell-function (quote ignore)))
```

The very same code under emacs works like a charm. In spacemacs, I can't obtain automatic numbering and not even the prefix with the file name.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think the issue is that spacemacs  does `(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX '(nil nil t t t)` in the function `latex/init-reftex` in the file `layers/+lang/latex/packages.el`.  You can test this by changing the line 158 to `(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)` in that file and see if it helps.  Next, you would have to find out how to make it permanent. Disclaimer: I don't use spacemacs.

Comment: I don't know how you guess that but it works !! Thanks.

Comment: My lucky day `;-)`.  You're welcome.  You should write an answer to your question and mark it as accepted so that it is closed.  I will not do it since I'm not sure how to make permanent changes to spacemacs defaults -- I can imagine that the file will be overwritten with next update of spacemacs.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Arah, it suffices to change the line number 158 of `./.emacs.d/layers/+lang/latex/packages.el` from

```
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX '(nil nil t t t))
```

to

```
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```